# How to overcome C# List<generic<T>> constraint

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

I have the following situation:

I have several Event classes that share common behaviour like StartEvent and StopEvent.
I also have a special class each Event class works with (like pickups and you need to collect all of them to finish the event)
So I thought I'd make the BaseEvent class generic and each derived version provides its special partner class so I can have a base implementation to keep each in their list etc.
Now the tricky part is, that I have an EventManager that needs to know all events. But as far as I know, C# is not capable of doing this:

```
List<BaseEvent<T>> baseEvents = new List<BaseEvent<T>>();
```

this simple restriction kills the whole concept. I read about using an interface parallel to the BaseClass to be able to put them into the list, but is that really the only option I have?

Comment: Why not BaseEvent, as the base class of BaseEvent<T> ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are going on about, but first thing that comes to mind is: `List<BaseEvent> baseEvents = new List<BaseEvent>();`

Comment: Given a generic class `C<T>`, `C<int>` and `C<String>` aren't "sibling" subclasses of `C<T>`; `C<T>` isn't a concrete class you can have a reference to. However, if `C<T>` is a subclass of `class B`, then `C<int>` and `C<String>` are both subclasses of `B`. Likewise, if `C<T>` implements `IFoo`, `C<int>` and `C<String>` both implement `IFoo`. So the standard solution to your problem is what musefan and DavidG suggest: Move everything you can into a non-generic base class or interface and inherit `BaseEvent<T>` from that.

Comment: good point guys. Either another subclass or an interface, alright.

Answer (score 3):

The simple option is to make `BaseEvent<T>` implement an interface or a base class:

```
public interface IBaseEvent
{
}

public class BaseEvent<T> : IBaseEvent
{
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
List<IBaseEvent> baseEvents = new List<IBaseEvent>();

baseEvents.Add(new BaseEvent<string>());
baseEvents.Add(new BaseEvent<int>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your code not compiling? Your implementation should work.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new EventManager<Partner>();
    }
}

public class EventManager<T>
{
    List<BaseEvent<T>> baseEvents = new List<BaseEvent<T>>();
}

public class BaseEvent<T>
{
}

public class MyEvent<T> : BaseEvent<T>
{
}

public class Partner
{
}
```

Comment: I think he has BaseEvent<string>, BaseEvent<int>, etc.

Comment: @Sebastian Schulz
this is exactly what doesn't work: `List<BaseEvent<T>> baseEvents = new List<BaseEvent<T>>();`